# Powershell catch dynamic variable and add to array

Tags: arrays, powershell, dynamic-variables

I seek assistance in figuring out how to capture new dynamic variables and add them to an array.

Below is a sample code that creates the variables.

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    New-Variable -Name "$($user)_pwString"  -Value ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,4)) -Force
}
```

This will create several variables as such: 
`$Guest01_pwString`
`$Guest02_pwString`
`$Guest03_pwString`

How could capture each of the variables it creates and add them into an array.

What I thought would have worked:

```
$secureStrings = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $secureStrings += (New-Variable -Name "$($user)_pwString"  -Value ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,4)) -Force)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `-PassThru` switch in order to pass the newly created variable object through to the output stream, and you can use that object's `.Value` property to access the variable's value:

```
$secureStrings = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
  $secureStrings += (New-Variable -PassThru -Name "$($user)_pwString"  -Value ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10,4)) -Force).Value
}
```

You can streamline your command as follows:

```
[array] $secureStrings = 
  foreach ($user in $users) {
    (Set-Variable -PassThru -Name "${user}_pwString"  -Value ([System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 4))).Value
  }
```

Taking a step back: Instead of creating individual variables, consider using an (ordered) [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables):

```
$secureStrings = [ordered] @{}
foreach ($user in $users) {
  $secureStrings[$user] = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 4)
}
```

You can then use `$secureStrings.Values` to extract the passwords only.

Comment: So I just tried your code for the hashtable, however how do I extract only the _name_ field. Also for any of these the array doesn't show the values as a variable. I'll need to pass each variable to `ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force`. I was trying to keep the values separate so I can convert the password to a secure string then extract the value to be placed into a CVS file.

Comment: Never mind on extracting the name, I had tried `$SecureStrings.name` earlier and returned no output, however second time round that worked. Just need to figure out how I would pass this through a loop to convert each variable into a secure string.

Comment: @Run.Bat, to get the names (keys) stored in the hashtable, use `$secureStrings.Keys`. You can enumerate the hashtable entries (key-value pairs) with `$secureStrings.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @Run.Bat, as for the array: I had assumed you only wanted to store the passwords themselves, not the whole variable objects, but if you wan the latter, simply omit the `(...).Value` around the `New-Variable` / `Set-Variable` call.